# r and shiny: reactive on dates

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem on building connection between the daterange input and the date information from my df. Here is how my df looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), y = c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-04", "2016-03-05", "2016-01-01", "2016-04-06"))
```

here is my code:

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sliderInput("date_range", 
              "Purchase Date Range:", 
              min = as.Date("2015-01-20"), max = Sys.Date(), 
              value = c(as.Date("2016-02-25"), Sys.Date())
  )
),
mainPanel(

  tableOutput(
    "view"))
  )
))
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})


output$view <- renderTable({head(datasetInput())})

})
```

Just don't know how to write the input in server so that y can be connected to the date_range selection. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Use `input$date_range`. You've got unbalanced and oddly-located brackets and parentheses you need to clean up if you want it to work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alistaire points out, you access the date ranges with `input$date_range`. This will give you a vector of two elements, the min and max of the range of dates. So to get the min you need `input$date_range[1]`, and the max is `input$date_range[2]`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sliderInput("date_range", 
                "Purchase Date Range:", 
                min = as.Date("2015-01-20"), max = Sys.Date(), 
                value = c(as.Date("2016-02-25"), Sys.Date()),
                timeFormat = "%F",
                step = 1
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput( "view" )
    )
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    ## note: y formatted as Date'
    df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
                                     y = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-04", "2016-03-05", "2016-01-01", "2016-04-06")))

    output$view <- renderTable({

        df[df$y >= input$date_range[1] & df$y <= input$date_range[2], ]

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is it possible to put this into the reactive function instead? Cause my df has been defined in the reactive input function and I'm not so sure how to embed this part into the reactive function to get them connected. Currently I receive error like this: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: @cat88 - I'm not sure I understand; in your question you don't have a `reactive( )` function